# Hyper-V role active slows server

Tags: virtualization, performance, hyper-v

I've been having io performance issues with two new servers, and while testing I noticed that when I had Hyper-v turned off at boot using "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off" that my disk tests showed a large improvement.  When hypervisor is turned on at boot, performance drops even with no VMs running, and "HV Host Service", "VMMS", and "vmcompute" services stopped.  Is this normal, or does anyone have an idea why it's happening?  Thanks!

System:
R620
Windows Server 2016
Dual E5-2650v2
128GB (16x8GB PC3L-12800R)
H710p mini mono
5x Intel D3-S4610 960GB SSDs in Raid 5
Intel X540 NIC

Test:
diskspd.exe -b4K -d60 -h -L -o1 -t1 -r -w10 -c50M e:\io.dat
Hypervisor active: 83 MiB/s
Hypervisor off: 101 MiB/s